# Swift converting NSDate to 24h Format fails on Device

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm facing an annoying error when i run my application on my iPhone6.
I need to convert an hour (picked by a datePicker) from 12h to 24h format.
Simple thing! Right, I'm pretty sure about that but... my code works on simulator but not on device.
The code is the following:

```
func convertTimeTo24HoursFomratString() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        // isFormatTime24Hours is a static function that returns me if the device has a 24h clock or not. It works fine both on device and on simulator
        //if NSDateUtility.isFormatTime24Hours() {
        //    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        //    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self)
        //}

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self)
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?
iOS version is 9.1 everywhere.
Thanks in advance for any answer!

[EDIT after Paul.s question]
On simulator it returns 24h formatted date (right).
On device it returns 12h formatted date (wrong).

Comment: What are the different results you get on device vs sim?

Comment: Is the device's locale different from the simulator's? For example, you might live in Italy while the simulator is set to United States. Different locales can give different results from NSDateFormatter. If you think this might be the problem, try changing NSDateFormatter's locale property to something static.

Comment: @icant So, my `NSDateUtility.isFormatTime24Hours` returns me `false` both running on device and on simulator. So I think is not here the problem. Isn't it?

Comment: Why does your code branch and provide two different formats anyway if you only want 24 hours? How do you know your `isFormatTime24Hours` is correct?

Comment: @Paul.s debugging and checking `isFormatTime24Hours`' value. I know that my device clock format is 12h so I know if it's correct. I just realized that i've pasted the 'if', it was my desperate test :) i'm going to comment it in the main post

Comment: I can never remember the specifics but when we have had an issue with 12 vs 24 hr in the past it's been resolved by explicitly setting the locale to `dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];`

Comment: This is mentioned in the [Date Formatting guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) under parsing dates

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html): set yourself to be a a formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`. Otherwise your device's locale will affect date patterns.

Comment: GOT IT! I've just added locale to my dateFormatter and it works!

Answer (score 2):

There's an example from Apple's developer library that might be related to your case.

> The representation of the time may be 13:00. In iOS, however, if the user has switched 24-Hour Time to Off, the time may be 1:00 pm.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1

I would recommend to avoid providing custom formats. Try to use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` if possible. This will ensure adaptivity for all your users.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
lazy var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH mm"
    return dateFormatter
}()
```

than U can call the function like this

```
let dateYour = YourTextField.text
date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateYour!)!
```

or

```
var date : NSDate
let dateYour2 = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

anyway since IOS9 U can pass nil in order ti use international format

```
var time = time.descriptionWithLocale(nil)
print(time) // 2015-10-30 14:12:18 +0100
```

Answer (score -3):

```
let date = NSDate()                     // 31 Oct 2015 14:04
let formater = NSDateFormatter.init()
formater.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("HH:mm")
formater.stringFromDate(date)           // 14:04
formater.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("hh:mm")
formater.stringFromDate(date)           // 2:12 PM
formater.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
formater.stringFromDate(date)           // 14:04
formater.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
formater.stringFromDate(date)           // 02:04
```

checked on simulator, checked on device ... so, hard to say ...

Comment: Yes, of course, but depending upon your device configuration, this behavior can change.

Comment: it is the same, even though i change my locale, last two outputs are the same (as expected) / iOS 7, iOS 8  iPhone, iPad and simulator, simulator iOS9, OSX 10.11.1, playground ...