# Swift : Convert 12hr time to 24hrs when device is in 12hrs formate

Tags: swift, datetime, time, nsdateformatter

I want to convert my 12hrs time into 24hrs. but when my device current time is in 12hrs it gives me error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

And When my device current time is in 24hrs then it gives me correct output.

I have used following code:

```
func getTimeFromString(timeString : String)-> NSDate
    {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter();
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        let date = formatter.dateFromString(timeString)//here timeString is "06:45 am"
        return date!
    }
```

My question is why it can not convert 12hrs time into 24hrs, when device current time is in 12hrs time formate?

Please suggest me any idea, code ,reference.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please provide an example of your input string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift converting NSDate to 24h Format fails on Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451082/swift-converting-nsdate-to-24h-format-fails-on-device) – set the formatters locale to en_US_POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

The input string you are providing doe not match the date format you specified.

A few changes to your function

1. It should return an optional `NSDate` (when the format is not recognized)
2. The format should be `hh:mma`

Like this

```
func dateFromString(timeString: String)-> NSDate? {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mma"
    return formatter.dateFromString(timeString)
}
```

Now you can use it

```
dateFromString("10:15am") // "Jan 1, 2000, 12:15 AM"
dateFromString("10:15pm") // "Jan 1, 2000, 12:15 PM"
dateFromString("NOT A DATE") // nil
```

Comment: `HH` is the 24-hour format, so `HH:mma` does not make much sense to me.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR, I changed `HH` to `hh`.