# NSDateFormatter not formatting date correctly

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I'm using NSDateFormater to format dates that i get from my server.
All the formatting works correctly except of AM/PM

```
    let f = "EEEE, MMM dd, hh:mma"
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = f
    let d = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
    print("formated date: \(d)")
```

i get:

> formated date: Tuesday, Feb 23, 11:30

and it should be:

> formated date: Tuesday, Feb 23, 11:30am

Am i missing something?

**Solution:**

My IPhones time is set to 24 hour format, i changed it to 12 and it also changed in my app.

Comment: just set `hh:mm:ss a` in place of `hh:mma`

Comment: It actually prints Tuesday, Feb 23, 11:36AM. Are you sure about the answer?

Comment: can you try   let f = "EEEE, MMM dd, hh:mm a" ?

Comment: Consider that the string representation depends also on the current locale settings

Comment: @vadian thanks, my Iphone was set to 24 hour format, i changed it to 12 and it works.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451082/swift-converting-nsdate-to-24h-format-fails-on-device ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
let f = "EEEE, MMM dd, hh:mm a"
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this and it works

```
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 let f = "EEEE, MMM dd, hh:mm a"
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = f
 let d = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
 print("formated date: \(d)")
```

Demo [here](http://iswift.org/playground?JCitn4)