# How to convert GMT string to timeStamp

Tags: swift3

my string is that: "Fri, 07 Oct 2016 00:00:00 GMT"
I try this:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
let someNSDate = dateFormatter.date(from: string)
let myTimeStamp = someNSDate?.timeIntervalSince1970
return myTimeStamp!
```

but someNSDate return nil
thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451082/swift-converting-nsdate-to-24h-format-fails-on-device/33451583#33451583: Set the dateformatter locale to "en_US_POSIX".

Comment: If your device's language isn't English, the date string won't parse.

Answer (score 0):

yeah!!! this works fine in swift3 ... thanks very much!!

```
class func timeStampFromString(string: String) -> Double {
   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
   dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en-US") as Locale!
   let someNSDate = dateFormatter.date(from: string)
   let myTimeStamp = someNSDate?.timeIntervalSince1970
   return myTimeStamp!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Implementing as follows returns the following for me:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
let someNSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("Fri, 07 Oct 2016 00:00:00 GMT")
print(someNSDate)//This is Fri, 07 Oct 2016 00:00:00 GMT
let myTimeStamp = someNSDate?.timeIntervalSince1970
print(myTimeStamp)//This is 1475798400.0
```

Are you sure all instances of the date string passed are in the correct format? This is a likely cause of nil returns from the date formatter.

Comment: you are rigth, but it works fine in simulator but donn't work in device... could be for the Locale???